# Reduce operation on custom object in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to use Reduce operation for performing sum on two fields of an object.

e.g.

```
class Pojo
{
    public Pojo(int a, int b) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    int a ;
    int b;
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}

Pojo object1 = new Pojo(1, 1);
Pojo object2 = new Pojo(2, 2);
Pojo object3 = new Pojo(3, 3);
Pojo object4 = new Pojo(4, 4);

List<Pojo> pojoList = new ArrayList<>();

pojoList.add(object1);
pojoList.add(object2);
pojoList.add(object3);
pojoList.add(object4);
```

I can perform sum using `IntStream` like this:

```
int sum = pojoList.stream()
                  .mapToInt(ob -> (ob.getA() + ob.getB()))
                  .sum();
```

I want to perform the **same operation using reduce**, but somehow I am not getting the syntax correct:

```
pojoList.stream()
        .reduce(0, (myObject1, myObject2) -> (myObject1.getA() + myObject2.getB()));
```

Comment: `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is incorrect btw, it should be `zero`

Comment: also you could perform a mutable reduction here... that is use `collect`, not `reduce`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, if you want to call reduce on the `IntStream`:

```
int sum = pojoList.stream()
                  .mapToInt(ob ->(ob.getA()+ob.getB()))
                  .reduce(0, (a,b)->a+b);
```

Of course, the same will work on a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
int sum = pojoList.stream()
                  .map(ob ->(ob.getA()+ob.getB()))
                  .reduce(0, (a,b)->a+b);
```

or with a method reference:

```
int sum = pojoList.stream()
                  .map(ob ->(ob.getA()+ob.getB()))
                  .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

or without the `map()`:

```
int sum = pojoList.stream()
                  .reduce(0, (s,ob)->s+ob.getA()+ob.getB(),Integer::sum);
```

In this last example, I use the variant:

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner);
```

since the reduced value (an `Integer`) is different than the type of the `Stream` elements.

The first parameter is an identity value - 0.

The second parameter adds the `getA()` and `getB()` values of the current `Pojo` element to the intermediate sum.

The third parameter combines two partial sums.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to use it on IntStream. How we can do this without IntStrem

Comment: You should explain that the mistake is that the reduce function has to take the same arguments as the output.

Answer (score 7):

`sum()` method implementation is as follows:

```
public final int sum() {
    return reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

Replacing `sum()` with `reduce()`:

```
int sum = pojoList.stream()
                  .mapToInt(ob -> (ob.getA() + ob.getB()))
                  .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Or, without `mapToInt()`:

```
int pojoSum = pojoList.stream()
                      .reduce(0, (sum, ob) -> sum + ob.getA() + ob.getB(), Integer::sum);
```

For more information, see [Reduction operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

The [reduce function you are using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is taking a BinaryOperator, which has takes two T objects as arguments and **returns a T object**.

What you want is this [reduce function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), which works with an accumulator, here is how to use it (see Eran's answer):

```
int sum = pojoList.stream()
                  .reduce(0 /* the identity for your binary operation, for sum this is 0 */, 
                         (s,ob)->s+ob.getA()+ob.getB() /* s is the accumulated value */,
                         Integer::sum /* combine accumulated values by sum */);
```

Answer (score 3):

Same as Eran's answer almost:

```
int sum = pojoList.stream()
                  .mapToInt(ob ->(ob.getA()+ob.getB()))
                  .reduce(Integer::sum)
                  .orElse(0);
```

Just for the fun of it you could do it with `collect`too:

```
int result = pojoList.stream()
            .collect(
                    () -> new int[] { 0 },
                    (x, y) -> x[0] = x[0] + y.getA() + y.getB(),
                    (left, right) -> left[0] += right[0])[0];
```

Comment: Or `.collect(Collectors.summingInt(pojo -> pojo.getA() + pojo.getB()))`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Pojo {
  static public Pojo add(Pojo p1, Pojo p2) {
    return new Pojo(p1.getA() + p2.getA(), p1.getB() + p2.getB())
  }
  //...
}
```

so later on:

```
Pojo pojoSum = pojoList.stream().reduce(new Pojo(0,0), Pojo::add);
pojoSum.getA() + pojoSum.getB()
```