# In Java, how to find the sum of several fields in a list of objects using stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

As shown below, I have a list of objects with integer fields like X2 and X3.

```
List<Object> objectList=new ArrayList<>();
objectList.add(new Object(X1="ABC",X2=1,X3=3));
objectList.add(new Object(X1="XYZ",X2=2,X3=7));
objectList.add(new Object(X1="AC",X2=1,X3=3));
objectList.add(new Object(X1="AB",X2=1,X3=3));
```

The goal is to navigate through this list and get the sum of all X2s and X3s.

I attempted the method below to calculate the sum, but I believe there should be a way to do it with one stream() call.

```
int X2Sum=objectList.stream().mapToInt(o->o.getX2()).sum();
int X3Sum=objectList.stream().mapToInt(o->o.getX3()).sum();
```

Comment: I am looking for individual sums of X2 and X3

Comment: Are you using Java 12 or higher?

Comment: No, I am using Java 8

Comment: Java 12 has [the teeing collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)). There is none for Java 8 unless you do it yourself, but I doubt it worth the effort. Keep what you already have or do it the traditionall way with a classic for loop

Comment: Does [Summing multiple different fields in a list of objects using the streams api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039318/summing-multiple-different-fields-in-a-list-of-objects-using-the-streams-api) answer your question?

Comment: If you need two result variables, then you need two streams (or a single stream which produces a temporary object from which you extract the two sums; nothing gained there except an extra class to implement and test)

Answer (score 2):

The `IntStream.sum()` terminal only returns one single sum per stream.
This means you need two separate streams for two sums like you already have:

```
int sumOfX2 = objectList.stream().mapToInt(o->o.getX2()).sum();
int sumOfX3 = objectList.stream().mapToInt(o->o.getX3()).sum();
```

An alternative way with only using one stream would require a [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) step as explained in [Reduce operation on custom object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582475/reduce-operation-on-custom-object-in-java).

```
List<Pojo> pojoList = new ArrayList<>();
pojoList.add(new Pojo("ABC", 1, 3));
pojoList.add(new Pojo("XYZ", 2, 7));

var pojoSum = pojoList.stream().reduce(
  new Pojo(¨sumX¨ 0,0), // initial result
  // the combiner is already the accumulator
  (pojoResult, pojoToAdd) -> {
    pojoResult.setX2( pojoResult.getX2() + pojoToAdd.getX2() );
    pojoResult.setX3( pojoResult.getX3() + pojoToAdd.getX3() );
    return pojoResult;
  }
);
```

See also:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-sum